# Initialising 'top' struct in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm currently attempting to initialise a struct with Swift, that goes several structs deep. Once an external API is called, it sends back data which I want to place into a struct so that I can use it to populate a TableView.

I'm wanting to decode data that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "quote": {
        "GBP": {
          "price": 25794.72142905233,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.4133929,
          "percent_change_24h": -0.74636982,
          "percent_change_7d": -5.8533249
        }
      }
    },
    "52": {
      "name": "XRP",
      "quote": {
        "GBP": {
          "price": 0.7157097479533718,
          "percent_change_1h": -1.35513268,
          "percent_change_24h": 1.84172355,
          "percent_change_7d": 5.05130272
        }
      }
    }
}
```

To do this, I have the following Struct structure:

1. Coin struct which references data
2. Datum struct which references the '1' and '52'
3. Quote struct which references the 'quote'
4. GBP struct which references the 'price', 'percent_change_1h'

These look like this:

```
struct Coin: Codable {
    let data: [String: Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let name: String
    let quote: Quote
}

struct Quote: Codable {
    let gbp: Gbp

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case gbp = "GBP"
    }
}

struct Gbp: Codable {
    let price, percentChange1H, percentChange24H, percentChange7D: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case price
        case percentChange1H = "percent_change_1h"
        case percentChange24H = "percent_change_24h"
        case percentChange7D = "percent_change_7d"
    }
}
```

I'm then attempting to set up a variable which is an empty 'Coin' struct under the variable name 'coins' like so:

```
var coins = Coin()
```

Unfortunately - trying to do this prompts the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'data' in call

If I then follow the prompts, I can insert the following:

```
var coins = Coin(data: [String : Datum])
```

But this then produces the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String: Datum].Type' to expected
> argument type '[String: Datum]'

Please can somebody point out what is going wrong here? Have I built my structs incorrectly? Is there an alternative I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `[String : Datum]`, which the compiler is telling you is a `Type`, use `[:]`, which is the Swift syntax for an empty `Dictionary`:

```
var coins = Coin(data: [:])
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for the response!